# How to know if agent is a mobile device - nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using nextjs(`10.1.3`).

I using this function:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const useCheckMobileScreen = () => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined"){
        const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
        const handleWindowSizeChange = () => {
                setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        }
    
        useEffect(() => {
            window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
            }
        }, []);
    
        return (width <= 768);
    }
    return false;
    
}

export default useCheckMobileScreen
```

now I call this function for my layout:

```
import useCheckMobileScreen from "utiles/useCheckMobileScreen";
export const ProductItem = ({product}) => {

  const isMobile = useCheckMobileScreen()
  let itemClass = 'product-item';
  if (isMobile) {
    itemClass = itemClass + ' full-width'
  }

return (
  <div className={itemClass}>
...
```

but when my page loaded at the first time my class 'full-width' added to my element.
but when I do refresh page, 'full-width' class name disappear!

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the handler so that the state gets updated with initial window width.

Also, don't use `useEffect` and `useState` inside a conditional statement. Use a conditional statement inside the hook (but it can be done without even that in this case). [Ref. Rule of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

And you should consider reducing the 768px width (IMO that's the dimension of tablets).

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useCheckMobileScreen = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleWindowSizeChange = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    handleWindowSizeChange();
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeChange);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeChange);
  }, []);

  return width <= 576;
};

export default useCheckMobileScreen;
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-jones-5q4wx).

---

PS: This method only checks if viewport width is less than a certain constant, but that doesn't always mean that the user agent is a mobile browser. If you wish to achieve the latter you may consider using some library like [`react-device-detect`](https://github.com/duskload/react-device-detect). Moreover, seeing your provided example, I think you can do this more easily using CSS media queries.